Static text before query column
I would like to insert a static text before column B in a query, unfortunately I get a blank line with "->"()
=query(FILTER!A1:U;"Select '->', B,U WHERE B is not null AND B >= date '"&TEXT(NOW()-10;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'limit 8")

I get this

"->"()    | 
->        |   04.05.2024
->        |   10.05.2024
->        |   11.05.2024

i want this
    
->        |  04.05.2024
->        |  10.05.2024
->        |  11.05.2024

What am I doing wrong?

try with adding the label parameter as: limit 8 label '->' ''
